# Problem when using thrust::iterator_adaptor on a device_vector

Tags: c++, cuda, iterator, thrust

I am working on defining an iterator_adaptor based on a base iterator. 
The whole thing works when working on host_vectors, but when I apply it to device_vectors, the compiler throws an error: initial value of reference to non-const must be an lvalue.

```cpp
#include <thrust/iterator/iterator_adaptor.h>
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>

struct BoxIterator{

  unsigned int m_loc;
 typedef int difference_type;
  typedef double* pointer;
  typedef double& reference;
  typedef double value_type;
  typedef thrust::random_access_device_iterator_tag iterator_category;
  __host__ __device__
  BoxIterator() : m_loc(0){}

  __host__ __device__
  void operator++()
  {
    ++m_loc;
  }
  __host__ __device__
  void advance(int n)
  {
    m_loc += n;
  }
  __host__ __device__
  void operator--()
  {
    advance(-1);
  }

  __host__ __device__
  void operator+=(int n)
  {
    advance(n);
  }
  __host__ __device__
  void begin()
  {
    m_loc = 0;
  }

  __host__ __device__ 
  bool operator==(const BoxIterator & other) const
  {return  m_loc==other.m_loc;}

  __host__ __device__
  bool equal(const BoxIterator & other) const
  {
    return m_loc==other.m_loc;
  }

  __host__ __device__
   difference_type distance_to(const BoxIterator & other) const
   {
     return other.m_loc - this->m_loc;
   }
   __host__ __device__
   BoxIterator operator+(int n)
   {
     BoxIterator tmp = *this;
     tmp.m_loc += n;
     return tmp;
   }
  __host__ __device__
  BoxIterator(const BoxIterator & other)
  {
    m_loc = other.m_loc;
  }
__host__ __device__
  BoxIterator & operator=(const BoxIterator & other)
  {
    m_loc = other.m_loc;
    return *this;
  }

};


template <typename LatticeIt, typename Container>
class SubVolumeIterator : public thrust::iterator_adaptor<SubVolumeIterator<LatticeIt, Container>,
                                                          LatticeIt
                                                          >
{
  public:
    typedef thrust::iterator_adaptor<SubVolumeIterator<LatticeIt, Container>,
                                     LatticeIt
                                     >
        super_t;
    __host__
    SubVolumeIterator(const LatticeIt &It, Container &FAB, int N) : super_t(It),
                                                                    v(FAB.begin()),
                                                                    offset(N) {}
    friend class thrust::iterator_core_access;
  private:
    decltype(Container().begin()) v;
    int offset;
    __host__ __device__
        typename super_t::reference
       dereference() const
    {
      return *(v + offset); //+this->base().m_loc); // this gives an error: initial value of reference to non-const must be an lvalue
                                // when thrust::copy is used on a device_vector. Compiles fine with a host_vector.
    }
};

int main()
{
    thrust::host_vector<double> HV(100);
    thrust::device_vector<double> DV(100);
    thrust::device_vector<double> DV1(100);
    BoxIterator bit;

    SubVolumeIterator<decltype(bit), decltype(HV)> HIt(bit, HV, 1);

    SubVolumeIterator<decltype(bit), decltype(HV)> HIt_end(bit + 20, HV, 1);

    thrust::fill(HIt, HIt_end, 5.); // this compiles fine

    for (int i = 1; i < 21; ++i)
    {
      std::cout << HV[i] << std::endl;
    }
{
   SubVolumeIterator<decltype(DV.begin()), decltype(DV)> DIt(DV.begin(), DV, 5);

    SubVolumeIterator<decltype(DV.begin()), decltype(DV)> DIt_end(DV.begin() + 20, DV, 5);

    thrust::fill(DIt,DIt_end , -5.); // this compiles fine
}
{
    SubVolumeIterator<decltype(bit), decltype(DV)> DIt(bit, DV, 5);

    SubVolumeIterator<decltype(bit), decltype(DV)> DIt_end(bit + 20, DV, 5);

    thrust::fill(DIt,DIt_end , -5.); // this throws the error

    thrust::copy(DV.begin()+1,DV.begin()+21, HV.begin()+1); 

    for (int i = 1; i < 21; ++i)
    {
      std::cout << HV[i] << std::endl;
    }
}


return 0;
}
```

Please do not answer by pointing out ways to achieve the same effect using the fancy iterators that thrust provides. I need to develop an iterator that adapts a class that steps over a lattice in a predefined way. This is the barebone code that gives the error. The code compiles
for a custom adapted iterator if in host, and for the standard iterator of device vectors for device vectors. When I use the custom iterator on device vectors the compiler throws the error  "initial value of reference to non-const must be an lvalue" at the location indicated in the example above. 
I compile it with nvcc  main.cu.  nvcc version 9.0, gcc version 7.3.0, thrust version 1.9.0

Comment: What thrust, cuda and host compiler versions are you using?

Comment: I tried CUDA 10.1 on Fedora 29  (gcc 8.3.1) and it threw the stated error.

Comment: I am using cuda 9.0 on an Ubuntu 18.04 Linux Box. The version of thrust is 1.9.0, host compiler is gcc 7.3.0

Comment: remove the 3rd template parameter (`double`) in both locations (the example code basically suggests to use defaults for parameters after the 2nd), and remove the `__device__` decorator from the class constructor (its not necessary for your usage), and the code compiles correctly and runs without error for me.  Furthermore, the `fill` results appear correct between `DV` and `HV` at the end.

Comment: I presume the compilation command included  in the edit is incorrect and the code is in a `.cu` file and not a `.cpp` file

Comment: Yes, I missed that, I was compiling my code in `.cu` file when I made my previous comments.  Compiling this code in a `.cpp` file will produce many other errors.

Comment: Without double, it does work in this example, However, when I use our own LatticeIt, it still won't compile for device. These are how we set the member types for LatticeIt when it is applied to a device_vector: typedef int difference_type;
  typedef double* pointer;
  typedef double& reference;
  typedef double value_type;
  typedef thrust::random_access_device_iterator_tag iterator_category;                My gut feeling is that I am doing something wrong with the member types...

Comment: I posted a modified version of the code that shows that when on device, and using a custom (albeit trivial) iterator, the code does not compile.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a solution. The issue has to do with the definition of the member types for the base iterator. Replacing the code above with this one

```
#include <thrust/iterator/iterator_adaptor.h>
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
template <typename T>
struct BoxIterator
{

  unsigned int m_loc;
  typedef typename decltype(T().begin())::difference_type difference_type;
  typedef typename decltype(T().begin())::pointer pointer;
  typedef typename decltype(T().begin())::reference reference;
  typedef typename decltype(T().begin())::value_type value_type;
  typedef typename decltype(T().begin())::iterator_category iterator_category;

  __host__ __device__
  BoxIterator() : m_loc(0) {}

  __host__ __device__ void operator++()
  {
    ++m_loc;
  }
  __host__ __device__ void advance(int n)
  {
    m_loc += n;
  }
  __host__ __device__ void operator--()
  {
    advance(-1);
  }

  __host__ __device__ void operator+=(int n)
  {
    advance(n);
  }
  __host__ __device__ void begin()
  {
    m_loc = 0;
  }

  __host__ __device__ bool operator==(const BoxIterator<T> &other) const
  {
    return m_loc == other.m_loc;
  }

  __host__ __device__ bool equal(const BoxIterator<T> &other) const
  {
    return m_loc == other.m_loc;
  }

  __host__ __device__
      difference_type
      distance_to(const BoxIterator<T> &other) const
  {
    return other.m_loc - this->m_loc;
  }
  __host__ __device__
      BoxIterator<T>
      operator+(int n) const
  {
    BoxIterator<T> tmp = *this;
    tmp.m_loc += n;
    return tmp;
  }
  __host__ __device__
      BoxIterator<T>
      operator-(int n) const
  {
    BoxIterator<T> tmp = *this;
    tmp.m_loc -= n;
    return tmp;
  }
  __host__ __device__
      BoxIterator
      operator-(const BoxIterator<T> other) const
  {
    BoxIterator<T> tmp = *this;
    tmp.m_loc -= other.m_loc;
    return tmp;
  }
  __host__ __device__
  BoxIterator(const BoxIterator<T> &other)
  {
    m_loc = other.m_loc;
  }
  __host__ __device__
      BoxIterator &
      operator=(const BoxIterator<T> &other)
  {
    m_loc = other.m_loc;
    return *this;
  }


};

template <typename LatticeIt, typename Container>
class SubVolumeIterator : public thrust::iterator_adaptor<SubVolumeIterator<LatticeIt, Container>,
                                                          LatticeIt>
{
public:
  typedef thrust::iterator_adaptor<SubVolumeIterator<LatticeIt, Container>,
                                   LatticeIt>
      super_t;
  __host__
  SubVolumeIterator(const LatticeIt &It, Container &FAB, int N) : super_t(It),
                                                                  v(FAB.begin()),
                                                                  offset(N) {}
  friend class thrust::iterator_core_access;

private:
  decltype(Container().begin()) v;
  int offset;

  __host__ __device__
      typename super_t::reference
      dereference() const
  {
    return *(v + offset + this->base().m_loc); // this gives an error: initial value of reference to non-const must be an lvalue
                                               // when thrust::copy is used on a device_vector. Compiles fine with a host_vector.
  }

  __host__ __device__
      typename super_t::difference_type
      distance_to(const SubVolumeIterator<LatticeIt, Container> &other) const
  {
    return (other.base().m_loc - this->base().m_loc); //+this->base().m_loc); // this gives an error: initial value of reference to non-const must be an lvalue
                                                      // when thrust::copy is used on a device_vector. Compiles fine with a host_vector.
  }
};

int main()
{
  thrust::host_vector<double> HV(100);
  thrust::device_vector<double> DV(100);
  thrust::device_vector<double> DV1(100);
  {
    BoxIterator<thrust::host_vector<double>> bit;

    SubVolumeIterator<decltype(bit), decltype(HV)> HIt(bit, HV, 1);

    SubVolumeIterator<decltype(bit), decltype(HV)> HIt_end(bit + 20, HV, 1);

    thrust::fill(HIt, HIt_end, 5.); // this compiles fine

    for (int i = 1; i < 21; ++i)
    {
      std::cout << HV[i] << std::endl;
    }
  }

  {
    BoxIterator<thrust::device_vector<double>> bit;
    SubVolumeIterator<decltype(bit), decltype(DV)> DIt(bit, DV, 5);

    SubVolumeIterator<decltype(bit), decltype(DV)> DIt_end(bit + 20, DV, 5);

    thrust::fill(DIt, DIt_end, -5.); // this throws the error

    thrust::copy(DV.begin() + 1, DV.begin() + 21, HV.begin() + 1);

    for (int i = 1; i < 21; ++i)
    {
      std::cout << HV[i] << std::endl;
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

results in a code that compiles and runs correctly. The main difference is in how the member types are defined in the base BoxIterator. 
Originally, I had them defined as

```
typedef double value_type; 
typedef double& reference;
...
```

whereas in the code now I added a template argument to the base iterator, which 
takes the Container. So now I have

```
typedef typename decltype(T().begin())::value_type value_type;
...
```

This fixes the compilation issue. Why the original code did not compile is still a mystery to me, but this offers a solution.